# Orocrm is not installed

Tags: centos7, failed-installation, orocrm

I want to install the Orocrm application on a Centos 7 server and I followed all of the following instructions step by step https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/manual-installation/commerce-ce/#step-3-oro-app-name-application-installation.

I put my Centos IP address as a domain name. But when I try to open the homepage with my IP address it gives me this current problem

[image: the application is not installed]

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This message is shown when the `installed` parameter is not set in the `config/parameters.yml` file. This happens automatically at the end of the installation process when everything is ok.

Most likely, you had some errors during the installation. Please check the log file in var/logs and the installation command log to find out what is the error cause.